# Using xonsh as python shell

Tags: python, comint

I'm trying to use [xonsh](http://xon.sh) as my python interpreter in Emacs (the one invoked by `run-python`). I tried to do this by setting `python-shell-interpreter` to `"xonsh"`. This works, but there are two issues:

- The prompt is printed twice (but results are only printed once)
- When I try to do something like `find-file` in a python buffer while the interpreter is open, this hangs (until I press C-g) and gives me thef ollowing in `*Messages*`:

  error in process filter: python-shell-comint-end-of-output-p: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
  error in process filter: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use for interactive xonsh sessions `shell-mode` instead. (It works well for me; after all xonsh is a shell.)

Read for install requirements from the xonsh documentation: [How do I use xonsh inside Emacs?](https://xon.sh/customization.html#use-xonsh-inside-emacs)

*In a nutshell:* Make sure you install xonsh with readline support and in your .xonshrc file define `$SHELL_TYPE = 'readline'` Also, in Emacs set `explicit-shell-file-name` to your xonsh executable.

Comment: In my experience can also use `(setq shell-file-name "xonsh")` instead of the `explicit-shell-file-name`. I'm guessing that would be convenient for running in the environment that emacs was started in instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Yes it works except if you call emacs's  shell-command with spaces in arguments. emacs escapes them with a back slash which xonsh doesn't understand - you can patch shell-command to work like msdos as that just surrounds the argument by "